# How do I use a state specific proxy?

Tags: proxy, geolocation

I need to hit a website through a state specific IP Address.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What is a "state specific IP address" in the first place? US states? HTTP states? TCP connection states?

Answer (score 1):

*(I'm assuming that you are trying to access a website which is distributed across multiple hosts w/ different IP addresses and you want to access a specific one of those hosts)*

If you're using Windows 2000, XP, or Vista, it's at %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (which path usually expands into c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
On Unix-ish systems, this would be /etc/hosts

Insert a line saying something like this:

`10.53.13.144 the-host-to-connect-to.example.com`

where the first part is the IP address this host will resolve to, and the part after the space is the host+domain name.

Save the file; some browsers (e.g. Opera, IE) need to be closed and reopened, since they are caching DNS hostnames.

This example means, that any request to the-host-to-connect-to.example.com will be sent to the host with IP address 10.53.13.144